# Finding text within files with filenames

Tags: bash, find

I have a number of clients running a piece of software within their public_html directory. The software includes a file named `version.txt` that contains the version number of their software (the number and nothing else).

I want to write a `bash` script that will look for a file named `version.txt` directly within every user's `/home/xxx/public_html/` and output both the path to the file, and the contents of the file, i.e:

```
/home/matt/public_html/version.txt: 3.4.07
/home/john/public_html/version.txt: 3.4.01
/home/sam/public_html/version.txt: 3.4.03
```

So far all I have tried is:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in 'locate "public_html/version.txt"'
do
        echo "$file"
        cat $file
done
```

But that does not work at all.

Comment: @Tshepang it is good that you are doing some cleanup in tags. Note, though, that `find` is a command in UNIX and is handy in questions like this one.

Comment: @fedorqui Am aware, but it is too often used in unrelated Questions, leaving it ambiguous, and therefore a bad tag. Even the tag wiki discourages people to use it.

Comment: @Tshepang not exactly. The excerpt says "This tag has multiple meanings. Please DO NOT use this tag if you're just trying to find something" and the tag wiki indicates the cases in which it should be used (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/find/info). If you are going to remove a tag in any cases, I think it is better to discuss it in meta beforehand.

Comment: @fedorqui it is still ambiguous, and ambiguous tags are bad tags. Replacements like [tag:unix-find] and [tag:jquery-find] would be better.

Comment: @Tshepang I agree find alone can be ambiguous. But again I suggest to discuss in meta. What for sure won't help is to just remove the find tag, because at least this question was previously searchable with "bash + find".

Comment: @fedorqui I put it back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /home -type f -path '*public_html/version.txt' -exec echo {} " " `cat {}` \;
```

Might work for you, but you can go without `echo` and `cat` ("tricking" grep):

```
find /home -type f -path '*public_html/version.txt' -exec grep -H "." {} \;
```

Comment: The second of these two lines works brilliantly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Or do it using find:

```
find /home -name "*/public_html/version.txt" -exec grep -H ""  {} \;
```

Comment: This command gives me an error. If I change "Name" to "wholename" however it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in /home/*/public_html/version.txt; do
   echo $i
   cat $i
done
```

will find all the relevant files (using shell wildcarding), `echo` the filename out and `cat` out the file.

If you want a more concise output, you should investigate [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) and replace the echo/cat with an appropriate regular expression e.g.

```
grep "[0-9]\.[0-9]" $i
```